# How to purge records older than 8 hours?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with records (database). In Column B is the date the record was created (dd-MMM-yyyy format). In Column C I have the time it was created (HH:MM 24hr format).

The problem I'm having, is purging the records older than 8 hours from current system time. This code works at purging previous day records for the current finance period, but it is not taking into account 24hr format and after midnight for records older than 8 hours. I have tried many different approaches to this but still unable to figure this out.

This is the code I have since the last time I tried to figure this out:

```
'------------------------
' Current Finance Period
'------------------------
cSheet = CStr(Format(cStartDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy")) & " - " & CStr(Format(cEndDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy")) `Set the sheet name to use (current finance period)
CreateSheetIf (cSheet) `Create sheet if not exists
cFTarget = wbFinance.Worksheets(cSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count `count the rows used
Set wscFinance = wbFinance.Worksheets(cSheet)
MRCForm.Caption = "MRC [ Processing... " & cSheet & " Ready to Finance records... Please wait... ]"
Me.sysMsgBox.Value = " Purging records, between " & cSheet & ", marked Ready for Finance..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If cFTarget = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wscFinance.UsedRange) = 0 Then cFTarget = 0
End If
Source = wsMRC.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set xRg = wsMRC.Range("AF2:AF" & Source)
Set dRg = wsMRC.Range("B2:B" & Source) `Date column in dd-MMM-yyyy format
Set tRg = wsMRC.Range("C2:C" & Source) `Time column in HH:MM 24hr format
On Error Resume Next
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If dRg(K).Value = "" Or tRg(K).Value = "" Or xRg(K).Value = "" Then Exit For
        If Format(dRg(K).Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") >= Format(cStartDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy") And Format(dRg(K).Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") < CStr(Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy")) Then ' If date is within current finance period then
            If CStr(xRg(K).Text) = "Y" Then
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wscFinance.Range("A" & cFTarget + 1)
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
                cFTotal = cFTotal + 1
                MRCForm.Caption = "MRC [ Processing... " & cSheet & " (" & cFTotal & ") Please wait... ]"
                If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Y" Then
                    K = K - 1
                End If
                cFTarget = cFTarget + 1
            End If
        End If
Next
Source = wsMRC.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set xRg = wsMRC.Range("AF2:AF" & Source)
Set dRg = wsMRC.Range("B2:B" & Source) `Date column in dd-MMM-yyyy format
Set tRg = wsMRC.Range("C2:C" & Source) `Time column in HH:MM 24hr format
On Error Resume Next
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If dRg(K).Value = "" Or tRg(K).Value = "" Or xRg(K).Value = "" Then Exit For
        If Format(dRg(K).Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") = CStr(Format(Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy")) And Format(tRg(K).Value, "HH:MM") <= Format(Now - TimeValue("08:00"), "HH:MM") Then ' If time is greater or equal to 8 hours ago then
            If CStr(xRg(K).Text) = "Y" Then
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wscFinance.Range("A" & cFTarget + 1)
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
                cFTotal = cFTotal + 1
                MRCForm.Caption = "MRC [ Processing... " & cSheet & " (" & cFTotal & ") Please wait... ]"
                If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Y" Then
                    K = K - 1
                End If
                cFTarget = cFTarget + 1
            End If
        End If
Next
wscFinance.Columns("A:AM").AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I know the code is not very clean, just trying to get something that will function for now, will try to clean it up at a later date. Might even look at creating Functions as reusable code is more efficient.

Comment: Can you combine the date/time into a single cell?  Excel should be able to do a time/date comparison for 8 hours before now.  If you're running into issues still, you should be able to convert it down to a normalized value, e.g., nothing today could be before 16:00 yesterday so you find the normalized number for the current minute compared to that starting point.   The latter is significantly more complicated, but would get the job done; similarly, you can store and compare inside of VBA rather than creating a new cell.

Comment: I can't combine the date/time into one cell. Their is a lot of other code that only use the date or time cells. Also, linked userform controls would have to be looked at. I would have to go through entire project to find and rewrite everything to do with date/time cells. I think I will have to read in both cells, combine into variable and process that. Just not sure how to go about that with above code.

Answer (score 1):

Mock-up:

- current time 11:45 on 2018.03.06
- storing log date in column A
- storing log time in column B

Untested code:

```
Dim i as long, lr as long, y as long, a as long, b as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i = lr to 2 Step -1
    y = TimeValue(now())-8 
    If y < 0 Then
        a = Date(Now())-1
        b = 24 + y 'y should be a negative value
    Else
        a = Date(Now())
        b = y
    End If
    If Cells(1,1)=a AND Cells(1,2)>=b Then
        .Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Intention of this code:

- loop through each row and delete the whole row if criteria met
- find what 8 hours before Now() was and store as y... with the current time/date it is 03:45 on 2018.03.06, y = 3:45

  - If we save the current time is 02:00 on 2018.03.06 then y = -6:00
- based on y being +/-, you determine the day and time

  - 24 hour based time for where y is negative, so you add the negative number... in the case of y = -6, 24+(-6) = 18, so 18:00 hours, and the previous date (z)
- you then assess the current row based on if the date matches AND if the time is less than or equal to z and y, respectively

This should be a starting point.

Comment: I have done something similar in the pass. Maybe I just didn't implement it correctly into the code above. I will have to take another look at this approach when I have more time to re-write the code.

Comment: @JDR360 The biggest issue I've had in the past doing something similar (executing *something* on a record based on when it was completed) was getting to the *If y < 0* part... it was honestly the key to getting the separation correct.  Mind you, I only had to worry about hours for my work, so those uses of integers subtracted may be an issue; just keep that in the back of your head, as you may need to use Hours() and Minutes() functions to get exactly where you want to be.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion above, I still have not been able to get it to work. When I put the Date(Now())-1 or Date(Now()), it throws a " Compile error: Expected: ) " and highlites " Now ". Not sure why it's throwing this error.

Comment: I changed it to " Format(Now() - 1, "dd-MMM-yyyy") and Format(Now(), "dd-MMM-yyyy") " and does look like it's working. Will test it when I have more data to work with.